# Is it possible to let an image overflow a div, without resizing the div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Background**

I'm creating a layout using Bootstrap 4.

Here's an image that *roughly* shows what I want to accomplish:

[image]

And roughly, this is built as such:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        <img src="..." style="width:100%; max-width: 400px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        TITLE
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

Since I use BS4, I have a responsive layout, such that all these elements become stacked on smaller devices, while maintaining the illustrated layout on medium devices and larger.

**My problem**

The size of the image is reasonable, but it pushes the line L2 (as shown in the picture) downwards unless I keep the image very small using the `max-width` css attribute.

**My goal**

What I would like is for that image to be a bit bigger *without* altering the height of the `<div class="row">` containing it. I.e., without pushing L2 down.

In other words, I would like for the image to be able to overflow its container.

Is this possible?

**What I've tried**

I've looked at the various `overflow-y` css attributes, but none of them accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Goal**

Answer (score 0):

You can always use z-index! Just set your first row position to "relative" and then apply the appropriate z-index. After this, just give your image container a set height that is longer than the containing div.

I created a simple working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/cf8z06ya/

```
.firstRow {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.secondRow {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
}

.overrun {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps a lot! The only problem now seems to be that the `.firstRow` div *needs* to have a fixed height in pixels. Is it possible for the `.firstRow` div to still scale based on the rest of its content? I also have a title in this div, which is of variable length.

Comment: Go ahead and post a snippet of your code so that I can more clearly decipher what you need :)